# How to render format JavaScript in a Rails controller

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, erb

I have a route called `"/admin"`, which is used to add and list products, from:

```
resources :products, controller: "admin"
```

In the controller admin I have a `create` function:

```
  def create
    @product = Product.new product_values
    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
        format.html { redirect_to :root }
      else
        format.js { render 'admin/error' }
      end
    end
  end
```

When I tried to make it render to format.js, it said:

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat
on `respond_to do |format|`
```

I thought  created `admin/create.js.haml`:

```
console.log("got it")
```

but it doesn't work.

Why did I want the response to be "format.js"? Because I want to add an error message to the form and don't want to refresh the page, so I respond to the JavaScript to `append` on some div with the error message.

This is `admin/add_product.html.haml`:

```
.p-5
  .container.column.justify-content-center
    %div.d-flex.justify-content-center.p-4#this-error
      %div
        %h3
          Add Product
    %div
      = form_for (@product || Product.new) do |f|
        .form-group.row
          = f.label :name,  class: 'col-md-2 col-form-label'
          %br/
          .col-sm-8
            = f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control'
        .form-group.row
          = f.label :stock,  class: 'col-md-2 col-form-label'
          %br/
          .col-sm-2
            = f.number_field :stock, class: 'form-control'
          .my-4
          = f.label :price,  class: 'ml-5 col-md-1 col-form-label'
          %br/
          .col-sm-2
            = f.number_field :price, class: 'form-control'
        .form-group.row
          = f.label :desc,  class: 'col-md-2 col-form-label'
          %br/
          .col-sm-8
            = f.text_area :desc, class: 'form-control'
        .d-flex.justify-content-center
          = f.submit "Add", class: 'btn btn-primary col-sm-8 p-2'
```

How do I use format.js in Haml for this?

Comment: `format.html` is handler for html request and `format.js` is handler for ajax request. You must be submitting form normally instead of AJAX and so get this error. Share your haml code as well.

Comment: just did, check above :D @AmitPatel

Comment: i want to add error message  on `id: #this-error` so I that is why I need to use javascript to not refresh the page when the forms is empty, so when i submit `"Add"` the form empty and must get error message

Comment: Add `remote: true` to the form if you want to make an ajax request

Comment: on where i must put it ??

Comment: Don't tell us "doesn't work". Tell us what happened that didn't solve the problem. You MUST give us details. See "[ask]" and its linked pages.

Comment: i think i already give the error message above,

Answer (score 1):

You are submitting a local request through the form, not remote (AJAX request) so your

```
format.js
```

will never be called.

what you can do is:

```
def create
    @product = Product.new product_values
    respond_to do |format|

        format.html { 
          if @product.save
             redirect_to :root
          else
             render 'admin/error'
           end
           }
        format.js {  }

    end
  end
```